# Python Buffer for large string - better or worse?

Tags: python, string, optimization, buffer

I am using python to take a very large string (DNA sequences) and try to make a suffix tree out of it.  My program gave a memory error after a long while of making nested objects, so I thought in order to increase performance, it might be useful to create buffers from the string instead of actually slicing the string.  Both version are below, with their relevant issues described.

**First (non-buffer) version** - After about a minute of processing a large string a *MemoryError* occurs for currNode.out[substring[0]] = self.Node(pos, substring[1:])

```
class SuffixTree(object):

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, position, suffix):
        self.position = position
        self.suffix = suffix
        self.out = {}

def __init__(self, text):

    self.text = text
    self.max_repeat = 2
    self.repeats = {}
    self.root = self.Node(None, '')
    L = len(self.text)

    for i in xrange(L):

        substring = self.text[-1*(i+1):] + "$"
        currNode = self.root
        self.branch(currNode, substring, L-i-1, 0)

    max_repeat = max(self.repeats.iterkeys(), key=len)
    print "Max repeat is", len(max_repeat), ":", max_repeat, "at locations:", self.repeats[max_repeat]

def branch(self, currNode, substring, pos, repeat):

    if currNode.suffix != '':
        currNode.out[currNode.suffix[0]] = self.Node(currNode.position, currNode.suffix[1:])
        currNode.suffix = ''
        currNode.position = None

    if substring[0] not in currNode.out:

        currNode.out[substring[0]] = self.Node(pos, substring[1:])

        if repeat >= self.max_repeat:
            for node in currNode.out:
                self.repeats.setdefault(self.text[pos:pos+repeat], []).append(currNode.out[node].position)
            self.max_repeat = repeat

    else:

        newNode = currNode.out[substring[0]]
        self.branch(newNode, substring[1:], pos, repeat+1)
```

**Second Version ** - Thinking that the constant saving of large string slices was probably the issue, I implemented all of the slices using buffers of strings instead.  However, this version almost immediately gives a *MemoryError* for substring = buffer(self.text, i-1) + "$"

```
class SuffixTree(object):

    class Node(object):
        def __init__(self, position, suffix):
            self.position = position
            self.suffix = suffix
            self.out = {}

    def __init__(self, text):

        self.text = text
        self.max_repeat = 2
        self.repeats = {}
        self.root = self.Node(None, '')
        L = len(self.text)

        for i in xrange(L,0,-1):

            substring = buffer(self.text, i-1) + "$"
            #print substring
            currNode = self.root
            self.branch(currNode, substring, i-1, 0)

        max_repeat = max(self.repeats.iterkeys(), key=len)
        print "Max repeat is", len(max_repeat), ":", max_repeat, "at locations:", self.repeats[max_repeat]
        #print self.repeats

    def branch(self, currNode, substring, pos, repeat):

        if currNode.suffix != '':
            currNode.out[currNode.suffix[0]] = self.Node(currNode.position, buffer(currNode.suffix,1))
            currNode.suffix = ''
            currNode.position = None
        if substring[0] not in currNode.out:

            currNode.out[substring[0]] = self.Node(pos, buffer(substring,1))

            if repeat >= self.max_repeat:
                for node in currNode.out:
                    self.repeats.setdefault(buffer(self.text,pos,repeat), []).append(currNode.out[node].position)
                self.max_repeat = repeat

        else:

            newNode = currNode.out[substring[0]]
            self.branch(newNode, buffer(substring,1), pos, repeat+1)
```

Is my understanding of buffers mistaken in someway? I thought using them would help the memory issue my program was having, not make it worse.

Comment: What kind of sequence files are you using and what size are they? Also what does your RAM look like?

Comment: I'm inputing FASTA files, which have no compression or anything, I'm running on a laptop with 16gb of ram.

Comment: What size is the FASTA file? Or if there are multiple, how many are there and what is their average size?

Comment: It's small as FASTA files go, its only 4.5MB.  I think that perhaps the way I coded my program is the issue.  In essence it is making objects inside of objects inside of objects, to a very deep level.  I believe that perhaps it runs out of memory at some point where it can no longer create another new "Node" object and gives the memory error.  I am unsure of how to properly debug the memory issues so this is just supposition.

Answer (score 0):

Working with sequence data can become memory intensive, especially if you are working with fastq files that are in the tens of GB range or larger. At a certain point, you're just going to need to use a machine with more RAM. Because you did not provide the file size information, or information about your compute resource, it is impossible to tell if this is the case. Please provide that info when you get a chance.

Regardless, it seems that you should be making use of some Bio python tools, which will make processing sequence data much more efficient. This is because much of Bio python makes use of C data structures.

First of all, you should be representing sequences as [Seq](http://biopython.org/wiki/Seq)s, not strings.

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq

sequence = Seq('ACTG')
```

Secondly, a suffix tree is a perfect job for a [trie](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.trie-module.html).

[Trie - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

```
from Bio import trie

self.out = trie.trie()
# You can work with this object just as you would with a dictionary.
# self.out[key] = value
```

Working with these biopython data structures should make things more memory efficient, and is just a good practice in general when handling sequence data in python.

Also, I am not sure what you're end goal is, but you may want to look into the more efficient suffix array. Many de novo assemblers such as ABySS use this for assembly.

Comment: My goal is less professional oriented and more learning oriented, so I am trying to create an implementation from my own skill set rather than using what comes with Bio python.  I am more of a science person and less of a program person so I was attempting to put my "paper" knowledge on suffix trees to use in Python as an exercise.  I would be happy to hear any suggestions about my suffix tree implementation however.

Comment: I see. I have the same background (biology first, then computer science). I am confused however, as my suggestions are simply two alternate data structures, so in essence you will still have to develop and implement the algorithm itself, just while storing your data in a more efficient way. I would be curious to see how replacing your self.out = {} with self.out = trie.trie() would work, as if I understand the code, that is where you are saving your nested objects, and the trie does not create the suffix for you, but rather serves the same purpose as your dictionary but more memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the '$' to your buffer is what kills it.  This causes it to coerce itself into a string, which causes all the same copying as before.  If you really need to append characters, you could try using a list of buffers instead of actually appending characters to a single buffer.